# gdal_calc equivalent in python

Tags: python, gdal

I have been using Python to perform `gdal_warp` commands like so:

```
options = f"-te {extent} -tr {pixelsize}"
interpolated_tif = gdal.Warp('c:/users/public/warped.tiff', 'c:/users/public/input.tif', options=options)
```

However, now I need to perform `gdal_calc` and `gdal_edit` commands in Python but there doesn't seem to be a `gdal.Calc` or `gdal.Edit` - how can I perform these commands then?

Comment: It may be clunky but I use subprocess.Popen, mostly so I can get a few processes running at the same time, not just for GDAL, it works with anything that can be executed from the command line. If you're needing a process to finish before moving to the next step then use process.wait() to halt execution until it finishes.

Comment: Gdal_calc and gdal_edit are Python scripts themselves https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_calc.py https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_edit.py

Answer (score 0):

```
from osgeo_utils import gdal_calc
ds = gdal_calc.Calc()
```

The function takes the following arguments:

```
calc: MaybeSequence[str],
outfile: PathLikeOrStr | None = None,
NoDataValue: Number | None = None,
type: GDALDataType | str | None = None,
format: str | None = None,
creation_options: Sequence[str] | None = None,
allBands: str = "",
overwrite: bool = False,
hideNoData: bool = False,
projectionCheck: bool = False,
color_table: ColorTableLike | None = None,
extent: Extent | None = None,
projwin: Tuple | GeoRectangle | None = None,
user_namespace: Dict | None = None,
debug: bool = False,
quiet: bool = False,
progress_callback: Any = gdal.TermProgress_nocb,
**input_files: Any
```

Some examples from the docstring:

```
add two files together:
    Calc("A+B", A="input1.tif", B="input2.tif", outfile="result.tif")

average of two layers:
    Calc(calc="(A+B)/2", A="input1.tif", B="input2.tif", outfile="result.tif")

set values of zero and below to null:
    Calc(calc="A*(A>0)", A="input.tif", A_band=2, outfile="result.tif", NoDataValue=0)

work with two bands:
    Calc(["(A+B)/2", "A*(A>0)"], A="input.tif", A_band=1, B="input.tif", B_band=2, outfile="result.tif", NoDataValue=0)

sum all files with hidden noDataValue
    Calc(calc="sum(a,axis=0)", a=['0.tif','1.tif','2.tif'], outfile="sum.tif", hideNoData=True)
```